# Pandas - repeating a string for each cells return one letter per cell

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

The code is scraping some text from a database, and creates a Pandas df at the end. I created the 'z' variable:

```
z = [y for y in x*len(b)]
```

that should take the name of the company (x from the loop) and write in column df['Input'] for many times as the length of the 'b' list.

The problem is that is printing one letter per cell as the length of the 'b' list.

I also tried:

```
z = [y for y in [x*len(b)]]
```

but it returns repeated names in a single cell based on the number of results

```
final_list = []
for x in short_list:
    search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('search_freetext')
    search_query.send_keys(x)
    time.sleep(2)
    search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    a = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.find_all('a',class_= 'title_link') if x.get_text().startswith(tuple(short_list))] 
    b = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.find_all('div',class_= 'dark_row regular_font')][0:len(a)]
    b = [' '.join(z.split()) for z in b]
    z = [y for y in x*len(b)]
    c = [list(pair) for pair in zip(a, b, z)]
    final_list.extend(c)
    go_back = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/a[2]').click()
    time.sleep(2)

df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['Company', 'Country', 'Input'])

short_list = ['comp1', 'comp2', 'comp3', 'etc.']

final_list = [['Global Health Limited', 'HeadquartersMelbourne, Victoria, Australia', 'A'], ['TWT Digital Health', 'Heidelberg, Baden-Württemberg, Germany', 'd'], ['Caspar Health', 'HeadquartersBerlin, Berlin, Germany', 'h']]
```

The single letters in final_list are actually the output from 'z', that should be one string from short_list iterated. For every company in comp_list there are n results found.

Current Output:

```
 Company                                            Country Input
0                               Global Health Limited         HeadquartersMelbourne, Victoria, Australia     A
1                                  TWT Digital Health             Heidelberg, Baden-Württemberg, Germany     d
2                                       Caspar Health                HeadquartersBerlin, Berlin, Germany     h
```

Expected output:

```
Company                                            Country Input
0                               Global Health Limited         HeadquartersMelbourne, Victoria, Australia     Comp1
1                                  TWT Digital Health             Heidelberg, Baden-Württemberg, Germany     Comp1
2                                       Caspar Health                HeadquartersBerlin, Berlin, Germany     Comp2
```

Thanks!

Comment: In `[y for y in x*len(b)]`, what's the type of `x`? Is it a list of strings? In this case maybe you want `[y*len(b) for y in x]`

Comment: @Max Hi, x it's a list of strings. Yes, I already tried it but it prints the single letters of x multiplied by len(b) in each cell.

Comment: Ok I didn't understand what's the expected result. Can you provide an example and more details?

Comment: @Max I updated my questions with outputs.